# Can NetworkManager temporarily not manage a modem device completely?

Tags: networkmanager, ttyusb

I temporarily want to send AT commands to a modem for development. But since I installed NetworkManager on my embedded system, I can't reach the at command port anymore (using `minicom`, it tells me: Device `/dev/ttyACM0` is locked.). To be able to send the AT commands, I currently take NetworkManager out of the autostart and then restart the machine. After doing the development, I have to include NM into the autostart again and then reboot.

Is there a better way? Preferably with NetworkManager commands and without system reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You can block a device in `NetworkManager` in any of the following two ways.

1. Go to device configuration file like `ifcfg-eth0` for the device `eth0` and add `NM_CONTROLLED=no`. In Fedora based system the configuration file will be in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-interface_name`. Then restart `NetworkManager`
2. Go to `/etc/NetworkManager.conf` and add `plugins=keyfile` in `[main]` section. Add `[keyfile]` section and update as follows.

   ```
   unmanaged-devices=mac:00:11:22:33:44:55;mac:66:77:88:99:00:aa
   or
   unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eth*,except:interface-name:eth0;interface-name:wlan*
   ```

Use proper device name in above edits and restart `NetworkManager.

This article shall be helpfil http://support.qacafe.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-prevent-network-manager-from-controlling-an-interface/